# cakephp: dont want to cache elements

Tags: cakephp, caching

I am calling several of these elements within my view:

```
<?=$this->element('overlay_panorama', array(
                        'id' => 1,
                        'header' => __('my header text'),
                        'folder' => 'files/folder/foo/',
                        'file' => 'bla'
                    ), array('cache' => false));?>
```

Inside the element I want to use the parameters like

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
<span class="folder"><?=$folder;?></span>
<span class="file"><?=$file;?></span>
</div>
<h2><?=$header?></h2>
```

But the first call is still caching the element and each element contains the same content.

Is there any better way of doing this?
Can I disable the caching anyhow? array('cache' => false) does not seem to take effect?

Comment: forgot to say: when I add <!--nocache--><!--/nocache--> arround the elements it still creates a cache file. And it doesn't matter if I have debug 0 or 2, I get a cache file in both cases.

Comment: Cake doesn't cache elements by default, it's likely you're looking at the wrong problem: please show more code and describe what's happening (as opposed to what you _think_ is happening).

Comment: This is happening to me using CakePHP v3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can disabed cache using below code uncomment from app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the question has several years, I think this answer could help others with the same problem.
The correct answer is that you should not send the "cache" key in the array of options, since **CakePHP checks to see if that key exists, and if that key exists, it activates the cache for that element, regardless of the value it contains**.
Therefore, to avoid caching an element, do not send the "cache" key in the array of options!